# angle brackets in math and text mode

Tags: math-mode, text-mode

I use `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` in a command

```
\newcommand{\qdist}[1]{\textlangle#1\textrangle}
```

which is used in math and text mode. In math mode, I get the error message

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textrangle invalid in math mode on input line 952.
```

what similar symbol could be used in both modes? I use Lualatex.

the MWE

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper
    ]{memoir}

\newcommand{\qdist}[1]{\textlangle#1\textrangle}

\begin{document}

text with \qdist{word} 

and some math 
\[   a = \qdist{symbol} \]
The multiple applications of a GIS can be summarized in three prototypical situations:

more text 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could incorporate an `\ifmmode` conditional, to use `\langle` and `\rangle` in math mode and `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` in text mode.

[image]

This approach works with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{textcomp} % for \textlangle and \textrangle macros
\newcommand{\qdist}[1]{\ifmmode\langle#1\rangle\else\textlangle#1\textrangle\fi}
\begin{document}
\qdist{word}, $\qdist{symbol}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* -- As @egreg has pointed out in a comment and in his separate answer, using `\newcommand` to create the `\qdist` macro, as is done above, can run into trouble. It's necessary to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: works perfectly - but I had hoped for some way to avoid the difference between math symbols and regular text symbols. I understand that the symbols in math are graphically different, but why are different names required (which confuse the user)?

Comment: @user855443 - I'm not in a position to answer a *why*-type question with any kind of authority. I can only offer a guess -- which, hopefully, isn't too implausible: the macros `\langle` and `\rangle` are specialized for math mode; in particular, they have status `math-open` and `math-close`, respectively, and they can generate "large" fences when used as `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle`. Rather than redefine these macros to make them usable in text mode, it was probably more straightforward to create new text-mode macros (`\textlangle` and `\textrangle`) from scratch.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. The drawback of this 'straightforward' solution is to learn two more commands and the possible interactions/incompatibilities between them. Latex is wonderful, but hard to learn (and I would not know how to do it without all the help I regularly get from StackOverflow and nice people like you!)

Comment: @Mico Try `$\begin{array}{c}\qdist{\alpha}\end{array}$` and smile! ;-)

Comment: @egreg what does the `{c}` do in your last comment?

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. The situation is bad under pdfLaTeX, but it's even worse under either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX!

Comment: @thymaro It's the column specifier for `array`.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you don't want that the typesetting of the argument to `\qdist` changes font when in math or in text, so a simpler

```
\newcommand{\qdist}[1]{\text{\textlangle#1\textrangle}}
```

might suffice. On the other hand, if this appears in an italic context such as a theorem statement, the effect would be unpleasant:

```
\newcommand{\qdist}[1]{\textup{\textlangle#1\textrangle}}
```

seems better.

If you intend that in math the argument to `\qdist` should be some math symbol, then in my opinion you should use two distinct commands, because the situations are different and semantics of commands is important.

If you don't want to follow the advice, use

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qdist}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \langle#1\rangle
  \else
    \textup{\textlangle#1\textrangle}%
  \fi
}
```

which differs from Mico's suggestion in two important details: it will work correctly in every situation (Mico's wouldn't) and keeps the output upright in any an italic context.